# New files in Download directory

Tags: security, downloading

I see the following two files in `the Download` directory: `Flash_Player.apk` and `securedownload.bin`. I am sure for 100% (well, for 99%) that I didn't download them intentionally. What are these files, what should I do with them (delete, I guess...). Is it possible to know, what program is responsible for downloading these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `securedownload.bin` file is from your email app trying to download/save an attachment. The app creates this file (no matter what the actual name of your attachment is) whenever you try to view or save the attachment.

The `FlashPlayer` installer may have been automatically downloaded by your Browser when you tried to view Flash content.

In either case, these files should be perfectly safe to delete from your Downloads, since no apps are supposed to store critical files there.

(if an app places critical files in the Downloads directory, the app doesn't deserve to be used!)