# How to open a securedownload.bin file?

Tags: files

I have an android tablet, which I don't know what version it is. I want to ask how can I open a securedownload.bin file? I'd downloaded it from an email attach, and I want to put it in other file in the tablet. And, how can I view a .rar file? Thank you.

Comment: What is this file for?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [another answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/43765/16575):

> The `securedownload.bin` file is from your email app trying to download/save an attachment. The app creates this file (no matter what the actual name of your attachment is) whenever you try to view or save the attachment.

So you first need to figure out how the file was originally named and rename it accordingly. Then you can tell from the file name what app may be suiting to open it.

As for `.rar` handling, simply [search for "rar" on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=rar&c=apps), which turns up tons of fitting apps right on the first result page, which can deal with `.rar`, `.zip`, and other archive files (e.g. [B1 Free Archiver zip rar unzip](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.b1.android.archiver) or [AndroZip File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agilesoftresource)).